# JSP for loop throwing exception

Tags: jsp, jstl

```
     <table border="1" style="width:300px">
     <tr><c:out value = "Ques. 1 ${question.question}"/></tr>
     <%
       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
       List<answers> ans = (List<answers>)request.getAttribute("question.answer");
       for(int i=0; i<ans.size();i++){  // LINE 14
       out.println(ans.get(i));
       }
     %>
```

This is jsp code!! I am new to JSP's.
"question" is an attribute which i passed in jsp from my controller. Also , "answer" is variable defined in my question class.

This is throwing a null point exception on for-loop at line 14 . Although my answer variable which is of **(List answer)** type has values

Thanks for help

Comment: If you have a controller, why do you put business logic in the JSP?

Answer (score 0):

Please use `JSTL` in your `JSP`.

It seems your `ans` is `null` so can you  verify value of `question.answer` while setting in request from controller

you can refer to below link to avoid scriptlet in jsp

[How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your getParameter name is wrong.
Your objects name is not "question.answer".
you have:

```
List<answers> ans = (List<answers>)request.getAttribute("question.answer");
```

probably should be something like:

```
List<Answers> ans = ((Question)request.getAttribute("question")).answer;
```